# How can I update existing SQL datasources (Live) to connect to correct views (reconnect) in Tableau Deskop?

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api, sqldatasource

I have one question. I am new in Tableau and I have to update existing SQL datasources (Live datasources) to connect to correct views (reconnect) in Tableau Deskop, because of some mappings/new data that were added to SQL database.

For the same reasons, I have to also create new Tableau datasources.

How do I do that, update existing SQL datasources and create new datasources? Also, for creating new datasources is it possible to do it from Tableau Server or just from Tableau Desktop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Tableau only allows you to create data sources in the desktop environment.

If your SQL source is using a SQL statement you can alter your query to bring in the new data and then refresh the extract.

It's worth noting that the desktop extract is no longer used once you've published your workbook to the server (until you need to make more changes in the desktop environment).

I find making changes on Tableau server limited, so it's almost always best to make significant changes on desktop.

Also, if you're changing to new data sources, once you've loaded the data into Tableau, in the Sheet view you should be able to right click on one source and choose to point your views to the new source.

It all depends on the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try that!